# How to open a sqlite file in Android Studio (3.0.1) / Device File Explorer

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have accessed my sqlite file under data/data//databases/. Then I tried to open it in Android Studio. I selected SQL File as the file type, but Android Studio showed me a sequence of characters. Not a browser of sqlite file.

Is there any way to fix this? Can I open that sqlite database file under an application like 'DB Browser for SQLite', without saving that file under a folder and opening it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't open sqlite files in Android Studio yet. Every day I do it this way:
stetho (http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) - powerful tool which allows browse tables and execute queries

or downloading DB file into my local file system (through adb or Device File Explorer) and open with SQLite Browser (https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score -2):

Please take a look at `SQLite Administrator`. It is a free software, you can open a database file, create tables, launch queries, etc. I use it quite often when I need to take a closer look at a `SQLite` db file.

You can try also this:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-see-database-tables-in-Android-Studio

Comment: I tried all of these, but I couldn't manage to open the sqlite database file from the emulator in the Android Studio. I think there should be a bridge between device emulator and the android studio. I installed DB Navigator as plugin, it runs inside Android Studio, but I have to save the database file to my computers Desktop to see what is inside the database file.